# Recurrence of a markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

I know that a symmetric random walk is null recurrent. Is it true in a more general setup?

If i consider iid symmetric integer valued random variable instead of Bernoulli rvs, will the random walk be null recurrent ?

Comment: At least if the increments are square integrable, yes.

Comment: Any hint on how to prove it?

Comment: Every textbook on the subject does this. Which ones are you using?

Comment: I read random walk from feller. And i had a short course on markov chains.

Comment: Perhaps of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031913/find-a-symmetric-random-walk-on-mathbbz-that-is-transient

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334527/integer-random-walk-with-step-size-governed-by-a-distribution